# Drivers for ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, drivers

I am using ubuntu 16.04.1, on a toshiba satellite C850d PSCC2a-00x001 and I don't have the proper drivers for the AMD Radeon HD 7310 integrated graphics.

Comment: I edited it. To clarify, I just want to know where to install / what commands I need to install graphics drivers.

Comment: Linux is based on an open source model and a lot of drivers are proprietary.  Linux users eventually become adept at the process of locating drivers.  Some places to look first: the computer OEM web site, the hardware manufacturer's web site, Linux forums (where other people have already dealt with the same issue).  AMD has driver downloads here: http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/linux.  Google also revealed this at our sister site, Ask Ubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/330030/amd-radeon-hd-7310-hdmi-functionality-on-any-ubuntu

Comment: BTW, I don't use Ubuntu, but the drivers may be available in their repository.  I think Ubuntu is pretty good about including proprietary drivers (some distros, like Debian, you need to access a separate repository for proprietary stuff, referred to as "non-free" for non-open source).  Open the Software Center or Synaptic and search for radeon.  If you can load it from your package manager, you will have the advantage that the system will maintain it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There *was* an option to install proprietary (closed source) drivers in Ubuntu in the past, including the `fglrx` (sometimes called also `catalyst`) proprietary driver for the AMD cards. However, this is no more possible for 16.04.

The Ubuntu 16.04 uses the Xorg server 1.18, the proprietary amd `fglrx` works with Xorg server up to 1.15 (stated by AMD) or 1.16 (stated by some users). It also has been told that AMD stopped the develompent of `fglrx` in favor of the new `AMDGPU-PRO`. If your card is new enough, you can use the new AMDGPU or even AMDGPU-PRO (with proprietary parts) on 16.04. If your card is not new enough, the best and maybe the only option is to use the open source `radeon` driver, that you are probably actually using right now.

As described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-initall-additional-drivers), check the first (or first two) top-voted answer to see, if you can actually get any proprietary drivers for your *graphic card* from official (tested by the Ubuntu developers) repositories. If there will be some driver listed, you can try to install it (at your own risk). If there will be no driver listed, your card is probably not supported by new proprietary driver. And again, you probably have to use the open source `radeon` driver.

Check also [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/815591/ubuntu-16-04-14-04-5-and-amd-graphics#815592) for the comprehensive informations regarding the AMD drivers on newer Ubuntu versions.